# Electronjs + Reactjs | Window server 2012 R2 hangs on app launch (white screen), works fine on windows 10 and windows server 2019

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, windows-server-2012-r2

Pretty much title.
Cursor constantly changes from standby to loading, but other then that the screen stays white.

I have tested it on windows server 2019 and it worked, same goes for my local computer which is windows 10.

I tried building a x32 bit version and it crashed.
There is barely any information on the internet regarding older versions, and the one thread I saw mentioned what Ive tried already.

Can anybody point me to the right direction? I'm kinda clueless right now and trying to compare things like .NET Framework and such (although I'm pretty sure it's not related at all?)

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm getting an error in the event viewer that theres a faulting modoule, and it is ntdll.dll
going to continue research for now!

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone sees this and have a similar issue:
1.The desktop on our citrix server was programmed to be located on a network share and not on a physical hard drive, so I had to move it to the proper folder.

2.The application worked only when I placed it on the local drive, and only as a 32 bit application.

I spent two days basically trying everything on a 64 bit application, because when I tested the 32bit one it just crashed, but it turns out they were two seperate issues which are finnaly resolved!